# Importing date from CSV file to PHP

Tags: php, csv

I can import the data from my csv file however, the date inside the CSV file is not saving. This is the data inside the CSV File. The two dates are not saving.

Program 1   Project 1   asdasd  Academic Department 1/20/2018   1/21/2018   High

PHP Code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
  $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
  if ($filename[1] == "csv") {
    $handle = fopen( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r" );

    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
      $project_id = mt_rand();
      $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[0]);
      $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[1]);
      $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[2]);
      $item4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[3]);
      $item5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[4]);
      $item6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[5]);
      $item7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[6]);

      $sql = "INSERT INTO project (project_id ,project_name, program, description, department, start_date, end_date, priority, status)
      VALUES ('$project_id', '$item2', '$item1', '$item3', '$item4', '$item5', '$item6','$item7','Ongoing')";
      mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    fclose($handle);

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: What are the type of columns `start_date` and `end_date` ?

Comment: Data type is only date

Answer (score 3):

The field of type [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) needs a date in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`.

Add these rows before the insert, using [date()](http://php.net/date) and [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$item5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item5));
$item6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item6));
```

With this code you set the format `YYY-mm-dd` for those two dates.

Complete code:

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";

if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
    if ($filename[1] == "csv") {
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
            $project_id = mt_rand();
            $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[0]);
            $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[1]);
            $item3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[2]);
            $item4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[3]);
            $item5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[4]);
            $item6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[5]);
            $item7 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[6]);

            $item5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item5));
            $item6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item6));

            $sql = "INSERT INTO project (project_id ,project_name, program, description, department, start_date, end_date, priority, status)
            VALUES ('$project_id', '$item2', '$item1', '$item3', '$item4', '$item5', '$item6','$item7','Ongoing')";
            mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
        }
        fclose($handle);

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Got this thanks I have one more question, In my csv file I want to add a column title the title must not be include to the import how can i do that?

Comment: For that, please post it as new question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the format is not good.

Try something like this :

```
$item5 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item5)) ; // $item5 = "2018-01-20"
```

before to insert into your table.

Comment: how can i get the data of the date if i use that code?

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, your dates are in the wrong format.

In addition to the other answers, you could also convert your date directly in MySQL with the [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
STR_TO_DATE('$item5','%c/%e/%Y')
```

So in your example:

```
INSERT INTO project (project_id ,project_name, program, description, department, start_date, end_date, priority, status)
        VALUES ('$project_id', '$item2', '$item1', '$item3', '$item4', STR_TO_DATE('$item5','%c/%e/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE('$item6','%c/%e/%Y'),'$item7','Ongoing')
```

For more information on the format specifiers see the documentation for [`DATE_FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)